# API that places decent Ads like in Gmail for Android

Tags: android, api, ads

I'm searching for an advertising API that matches the above mentioned criteria. 
I don't want to show ugly or annoying ads. But I couldn't find a way of doing it.

Here is a picture of what I am looking for.

[image: gmail screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is **Native Ads**.  Most ad SDKs have native ads these days.  For example, here is the documentation for [Yahoo Flurry's Native ads.](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/android/#android-sdk-integration-native-display-integration-code).  Native ads will give you the pieces of information you need to display for the ad (title, description, image, etc.) and then leave the displaying part up to you so that you can seamlessly integrate them into your UI.